# Does Vue 3 Disable Prefetch for Lazily-Loaded Routes

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-cli

EDIT: My problem was that I had a typo in the way I was dynamically importing my component. I was incorrectly using:

```
const ShoppingCart = import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */'../cart/ShoppingCart.vue')
```

When I should have been using:

```
const ShoppingCart = () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */'../cart/ShoppingCart.vue')
```

This was causing it to always load the file immediately instead of lazily,.

---

I cannot figure out how to disable pre-fetching of lazily-loaded routes. The [documentation for prefetch here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch) suggests that we can fix this by removing or modifying the prefetch plugin as follows:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // remove the prefetch plugin
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')

    // or:
    // modify its options:
    config.plugin('prefetch').tap(options => {
      options[0].fileBlacklist = options[0].fileBlacklist || []
      options[0].fileBlacklist.push(/myasyncRoute(.)+?\.js$/)
      return options
    })
  }
}
```

However, that plugin doesn't appear to exist when doing a `vue inspect` and therefore, removing it as suggested does nothing.

Here are some old but related conversations on this topic:

- [Document how to disable/customize the prefetch plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/979)
- [Lazy loading chunks downloaded before route visiting](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1153)

Comment: I would suggest to migrate to Vite